# Savon Not Working As Expected With Stamps.com API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon, stamps.com

I am using [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) to make SOAP calls to Stamps.com API. I can make the initial call successfully. I can also make a call to one of the many NameSpaces, but they require 'additional content'(params) passed in.

When I use the AuthenticateUser method like this `client.call(:authenticate_user)`, it gives the following error:

```
(soap:Client) Invalid SOAP message due to XML Schema validation failure. The element 'AuthenticateUser' in namespace 'http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2016/12/swsim/swsimv57' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Credentials' in namespace 'http://stamps.com/xml/namespace/2016/12/swsim/swsimv57'.
```

I have tried passing in `:credentials`, but that returns this error:

`Unknown local option: :credentials`

Am I missing something, or is Savon not cooperating with Stamps.com API?

Comment: Have you tried to build your request with SoapUI?

Comment: I am trying now, but how will this help me with my RoR app?

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question, but i ran into the same situation and wanted to leave an answer so people who stumble on this have an answer.

for SAVON to work, you gotta make two changes:

1. the hash keys need to be a string and not a symbol
2. instead of using the newer javascript like ':' hash, you need to use the good old double arrow.

```
    hash = {
        'Key1' => 'Value1',
        'Key2' => 'Value2'
    }
```